# I can't bind or access image view on fragment

Tags: java, android

I need to use Picasso with ImageView but . I can't bind or access image view on fragment it's return redundant . Pls Help Thank You

[image]

Comment: A simple google would have answered your question. Redundant means extra or unnecessary. remove the cast. Thats it.

Answer (score 3):

Find the solution

**Above  or equal to API 26** onwards no need to cast any view

```
Imageview img = rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
```

If your using **below API 26** you should cast view

```
Imageview img = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
```

For more info, please find the below link

[No need to cast the result of findViewById?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44902651/no-need-to-cast-the-result-of-findviewbyid)

Answer (score 0):

Starting with API 26, **`findViewById`** uses inference for its return type, so you no longer have to cast.

```
<T extends View> T findViewById(int id)
```

old signature for Before **API** level 26

```
public View findViewById(int id){

}
```

new signature for starting from **API** level 26

```
public <T extends View > T findViewById(int id){

}
```

> Redundant means extra or unnecessary
>   it is just `warning` and it says that no need to casting

try like this

```
Imageview img = rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
```