# App stops working when register button is clicked

Tags: java, android

i want to register then when clicked on register button a verification email is sent to the email address.on clicking the link in the email.the email is verified.and the user can now login from the login screen.

RegisterActivity.java

```
public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "RegisterActivity";
private Context mContext;
private String email, username, password;
private EditText mEmail, mPassword, mUsername;
private TextView loadingPleaseWait;
private Button btnRegister;
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private FirebaseMethods firebaseMethods;
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference myRef;
private String append = "";


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    mContext = RegisterActivity.this;
    //mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    firebaseMethods = new FirebaseMethods(mContext);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: started.");
    initWidgets();
    setupFirebaseAuth();
    init();
}

private void init(){
    btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            email = mEmail.getText().toString();
            username = mUsername.getText().toString();
            password = mPassword.getText().toString();
            if(checkInputs(email, username, password)){
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                loadingPleaseWait.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                firebaseMethods.registerNewEmail(email, password, username);
            }
        }
    });
}

private boolean checkInputs(String email, String username, String password){
    Log.d(TAG, "checkInputs: checking inputs for null values.");
    if(email.equals("") || username.equals("") || password.equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "All fields must be filled out.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private void initWidgets(){
    Log.d(TAG, "initWidgets: Initializing Widgets.");
    mEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_email);
    mUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_username);
    btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    loadingPleaseWait = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loadingPleaseWait);
    mPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_password);
    mContext = RegisterActivity.this;
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    loadingPleaseWait.setVisibility(View.GONE);

}

private boolean isStringNull(String string){
    Log.d(TAG, "isStringNull: checking string if null.");

    if(string.equals("")){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}


private void setupFirebaseAuth(){
    Log.d(TAG, "setupFirebaseAuth: setting up firebase auth.");

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();

    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());

                myRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        //1st check: Make sure the username is not already in use
                        if(firebaseMethods.checkIfUsernameExists(username, dataSnapshot)){
                            append = myRef.push().getKey().substring(3,10);
                            Log.d(TAG, "onDataChange: username already exists. Appending random string to name: " + append);
                        }
                        username = username + append;

                        //add new user to the database
                        firebaseMethods.addNewUser(email, username, "", "", "");

                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Signup successful. Sending verification email.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        mAuth.signOut();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });

                finish();

            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
            // ...
        }
    };
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}
}
```

Here are the firebase methods like to register new email,add new user, send verification email etc...

FirebaseMethods.java

```
public class FirebaseMethods {

private static final String TAG = "FirebaseMethods";

//firebase
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
private DatabaseReference myRef;
private String userID;

private Context mContext;

public FirebaseMethods(Context context) {
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
    mContext = context;

    if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
        userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    }
}

public boolean checkIfUsernameExists(String username, DataSnapshot datasnapshot){
    Log.d(TAG, "checkIfUsernameExists: checking if " + username + " already exists.");

    User user = new User();

    for (DataSnapshot ds: datasnapshot.child(userID).getChildren()){
        Log.d(TAG, "checkIfUsernameExists: datasnapshot: " + ds);

        user.setUsername(ds.getValue(User.class).getUsername());
        Log.d(TAG, "checkIfUsernameExists: username: " + user.getUsername());

        if(StringManipulation.expandUsername(user.getUsername()).equals(username)){
            Log.d(TAG, "checkIfUsernameExists: FOUND A MATCH: " + user.getUsername());
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Register a new email and password to Firebase Authentication
 * @param email
 * @param password
 * @param username
 */
public void registerNewEmail(final String email, String password, final String username){
    mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.auth_failed,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                    else if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        //send verification email
                        sendVerificationEmail();

                        userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: Authstate changed: " + userID);
                    }

                }
            });
}

public void sendVerificationEmail(){
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    if (user != null){
        user.sendEmailVerification()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){

                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(mContext,"Couldn't send verification email.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}

public void addNewUser(String email, String username, String description, String website, String profile_photo){

    User user = new User( userID,  1,  email,  StringManipulation.condenseUsername(username) );

    myRef.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_users))
            .child(userID)
            .setValue(user);


    UserAccountSettings settings = new UserAccountSettings(
            description,
            username,
            0,
            0,
            0,
            profile_photo,
            username,
            website
    );

    myRef.child(mContext.getString(R.string.dbname_user_account_settings))
            .child(userID)
            .setValue(settings);

}

}
```

This are the log lines....

01-09 13:16:06.014 21548-21548/com.example.vishal.myinstagram D/RegisterActivity: onAuthStateChanged:signed_out

01-09 13:16:06.015 21548-21588/com.example.vishal.myinstagram D/FA: Connected to remote service

01-09 13:16:06.015 21548-21588/com.example.vishal.myinstagram V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4

01-09 13:16:06.017 21548-21994/com.example.vishal.myinstagram W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/data/com.google.android.gms/app_chimera/m/0000003a/n/arm64-v8a

01-09 13:16:11.043 21548-21588/com.example.vishal.myinstagram V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service

01-09 13:16:21.029 21548-21548/com.example.vishal.myinstagram W/Settings: Setting device_provisioned has moved from android.provider.Settings.Secure to android.provider.Settings.Global.

01-09 13:16:21.957 21548-21548/com.example.vishal.myinstagram W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.

01-09 13:16:32.737 21548-21548/com.example.vishal.myinstagram D/RegisterActivity: checkInputs: checking inputs for null values.

01-09 13:16:32.743 21548-21548/com.example.vishal.myinstagram W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms

01-09 13:16:34.088 21548-21548/com.example.vishal.myinstagram D/FirebaseMethods: createUserWithEmail:onComplete:false

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Add Exception log

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: it toasts failed to aunthenticate and in the log shows this "D/FirebaseMethods: createUserWithEmail:onComplete:false" and i dont even have any user in my database

Comment: Check Log and post error that you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

So before you can set any `OnClickListener` on a view, you must first initialize a variable with `findViewById(R.id.button_register)`. For example,

```
private Button registerButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    registerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_register);
    registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //handle click event
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

It is worth a mention that if you are using the support library >26 you do not need to cast the view anymore and can omit the `(Button)` in the initialization of `registerButton`. Android Studio should even prompt you that casting is no longer necessary.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44903372/7900721

Now the `R.id` is something that is set upon the view in the layout XML file.

```
 <Button
 android:id="@+id/button_register"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="@string/my_button_text"/>
```

Search for findViewById in the docs for more information
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html

Just a recommendation for some cleaner code that is more readable, I'd recommend creating a private variable of `View.OnClickListener` that you pass in as the listener as shown below.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    fab.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
}

/**
 * Handle click listeners
 */
private View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //handle click event here
    }
};
```

So if you begin to handle multiple click events, you could handle them in one section. As far as readability for others to maintain the code, it keeps methods such as `onCreate()` more concise with purpose of where each action is handled instead of scanning through multiple anonymous classes which would need to be instantiated for each `setOnClickListener`

Comment: I am now realizing you do initialize with `findViewById` in the `initWidget()` function. So I doubt this answer will actually help you but maybe something might learn something from it. How exactly does it stop working? Do you have the crash logs? Curious if its a firebase error or client side error?

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved...their was a problem in my jason file...anyway thanks everyone...