# What's the reverse of using BindView with Butterknife?

Tags: android

I'm trying to write the below code without using the Butterknife method, mostly for learning purposes. Can anyone help with writing it without it's use please?

I'm guessing it's something along the lines of

```
TextView textName = findViewById(R.id.post_title);
```

but it doesn't seem the run the same so I'm guessing I'm missing something

```
public class FriendsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @BindView(R.id.name)
    TextView textName;
    @BindView(R.id.image)
    CircleImageView imageView;
    @BindView(R.id.title)
    TextView textTitle;
    @BindView(R.id.company)
    TextView textCompany;

    public FriendsHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you probably know, ButterKnife is an annotation processor that takes your code at compile time, evaluates the annotations (eg. `@BindView`) and generates code to replace them with.

Now in the case of `@BindView` what the annotation processor actually does is:

1. find the desired view by its ID

and

2. cast it to the expected type.

So a functional equivalent of your example would be something like this:

```
public class FriendsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView textName;
    private CircleImageView imageView;
    private TextView textTitle;
    private TextView textCompany;

    FriendsHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        bindViews(itemView);
    }

    private void bindViews(View root) {
        textName = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.name);
        imageView = (CircleImageView) root.findViewById(R.id.image);
        textTitle = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.title);
        textCompany = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.company);
    }
}
```

You can read more about the underlying processes [in this blog post](https://medium.com/@lgvalle/how-butterknife-actually-works-85be0afbc5ab) or have a look at [some of the ButterKnife source code](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/master/butterknife/src/main/java/butterknife/internal/Utils.java#L108).

Where you can see that essentially what they do is look for the ID on the source view and try to cast it to the expected type that was read from the annotated field.

Excerpt from `butterknife.internal.Utils`:

```
public static <T> T findRequiredViewAsType(View source, @IdRes int id, String who, Class<T> cls) {
    View view = findRequiredView(source, id, who);
    return castView(view, id, who, cls);
}

public static View findRequiredView(View source, @IdRes int id, String who) {
    View view = source.findViewById(id);
    if (view != null) {
      return view;
    }
    // If view is null throw IllegalStateException
}

public static <T> T castView(View view, @IdRes int id, String who, Class<T> cls) {
    try {
      return cls.cast(view); // <-- casting 
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException
        // Exception handling...
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is how you can do it when compile SDK version is greater than or equal to 26:

```
public class FriendsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView textName;
    CircleImageView imageView;
    TextView textTitle;
    TextView textCompany;

    public FriendsHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        textTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        textCompany = itemView.findViewById(R.id.company);
    }
}
```

For API versions less than 26 you just need to explicit typecast the view returned by `findViewById` method to the field type.

Comment: I believe you are missing the explicit casts to the fields expected types. As it stands `findViewById` will only return a `View` object

Comment: @DanielW. That was the old way. If you compile with the latest Android SDK version there is no need for explicit typecasting. You may refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44902651/no-need-to-cast-the-result-of-findviewbyid?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Awesome! Didn't notice they improved this. Have been using Kotlin for so long :P ...there only seems to be a small caveat. From the answer you linked: "So if your compileSdk is at least 26, it means that you can make use of this :)". Maybe mention that limitation in your answer? Just in case someone trips over it

Comment: `findViewById()` supports generics now: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)

Comment: @DanielW. Now I have added that. Thanks.