# ImageView' is redundant

Tags: android-studio, findviewbyid

How to Solve this warning **Casting 'findViewById(R.id.catImageView)' to 'ImageView' is redundant less... (Ctrl+F1) 
This inspection reports unnecessary cast expressions.**[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/in0NC.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No need to cast the result of findViewById?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44902651/no-need-to-cast-the-result-of-findviewbyid)

Comment: [Edit] the question and show the [mcve] and the whole formatted text of the warning or errors.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.catImageView); 
which works same but removes your warning..