# how to get rid of this error 'casting findViewById to EditText is redundant'?

Tags: java, android

I'm new to Java and Android Studio. How can I use this line of code in my program? I can't use casting anymore in API 26.

```java
public <T extends View > T findViewById(int id)
```

[image]

Comment: Please refer the following description: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44903372/6532155

Comment: Simply remove the casting. It was necessary a long time ago, but now the compiler interferes it correctly.

Comment: How can I use this line of code in my program? I'm just a beginner 

public <T extends View > T findViewById(int id)

Answer (score 1):

It's not an error - now you don't have to cast your views into the type(like casting to editText).
If before you had to do :

```
 editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.id);
```

You don't need it anymore and you can just do this :

```
 editText = findViewById(R.id.id);
```

Comment: the problem remains the same, if i put the code you answered, it shows 'cannot resolve symbol usernameEditText

Comment: Check if you have an editText with that id (in the layout of your activity)

Answer (score 0):

So if your compileSdk is at least 26, that means no need to typeCast the EditText.
You can simply use:

```
 EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.my_edittext);
```

Comment: the problem remains the same, can you just tell me how can i use 
public <T extends View > T findViewById(int id)
in my code? i'm just a beginner sorry :(

Comment: @Hamza, you can directly use `editText =  findViewById(R.id.my_edittext);` no need to typecast with any view. The error which you are getting is `not the error` it is just the `warning`. You can remove the warning just by writing `editText = findViewById(R.id.my_edittext);`