# findViewById not accepting type argument even with compileSdkVersion 30

Tags: java, android, findviewbyid

I generally use kotlin for android but my college wants me to use Java. So I created a new java project in android studio.

The problem is I don't want to cast the return value of `findViewById()` manually. Instead I want to pass `EditText` as type parameter which the function is not accepting as anticipated. I get the error :

```
/home/onkar/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication2/app/src/main/java/io/github/omkar76/myapplication/MainActivity.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
        Log.d("EDITTEXT", findViewById<EditText>(R.id.first_name).getText());
                          ^
  symbol:   variable findViewById
  location: class MainActivity
```

Why isn't this working? Why is method not found? I even checked source of `AppCompatActivity` and it does contain required method:

```
 @Override
    public <T extends View> T findViewById(@IdRes int id) {
        return getDelegate().findViewById(id);
    }
```

My Java code is :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Log.d("EDITTEXT", findViewById<EditText>(R.id.first_name).getText());
    }
}
```

If I don't pass type argument `EditText`, findViewById returns `View` which then I need to manually cast. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44902651/no-need-to-cast-the-result-of-findviewbyid/44903372/) starting with api 26 you don't need to cast the returned value. I have API 30 SDK. So why this is not working. I am aware of workarounds like assigning return value to an `EditText` reference but my interest is in knowing why existig approach doesn't work.

Let me know if any other details are required. Please point out what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Whats the issue with using `(EditText)findviewbyid`? or why do you want to cast the value when using `findviewbyid` while youre targeting an api of 30 ?

Comment: @lyncx, as said in linked post with api 26 and higher you don't need to cast. So I don't want to use `(EditText)findviewbyid(R.id.first_name)`. Second, because `findViewById` is always returning `View` (not `EditText` as I want). Return value being `View`, I can't call `.getText()` which I want to. I want to know what's wrong with my code.

Comment: edittext is a **view**. findviewby id returns a view that you have defined in your xml. Still dont get why it is necessary to pass a paramenter. View is a parent class of all views for example edittext

Comment: @lyncx, In short "I can't call getText() on View instance"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're confused with the syntax of java.

Here `public <T extends View> T findViewById(@ResId int id)` means :

return value cast to T, T is resolved with the left side of the assignment declaration before the equals sign. In the following example

```
Edittext x = view.findViewById(R.id.abc)
```

So here T get assigned as Edittext as Edittext is on the left side of the assignment declaration which then returns edittext as a view. Then you can call x to getstring.
Hope this makes it clearer

Comment: Got it. Return type is inferred from reference it's assigned to. And there seems to be no way to explicitly pass type arguments as you can do in C++ or Kotlin. Thanks.

Comment: For findViewById, yes

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Java has no such syntax as Kotlin for *findViewById*.

The Kotlin syntax:

```
findViewById<EditText>(R.id.first_name)
```

The equivalent in Java:

```
(EditText)findViewById(R.id.first_name);
```

So, you can do like this in java:

```
Log.d("EDITTEXT", ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.first_name)).getText().toString());
```

Note: You have to put ***toString()*** to convert from ***Editable*** to ***String*** explicitly in Java

Comment: For future references to Omkar, if something works in Kotlin, but not in Java, it can be useful to decompile the Kotlin code to Java to see the differences in the languages. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34957430/how-to-convert-a-kotlin-source-file-to-a-java-source-file

Comment: That's not casting syntax in kotlin either. It's just type argument to generic method `findViewById()`. If you are correct how we pass type argument to, for example, `new ArrayList<Integer>` in java?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way use a variable name

```
EditText editext = findViewById(R.id.first_name);
```

then you could use

```
 Log.d("EDITTEXT", editext.getText().toString());
```

Comment: I have mentioned in my post that I know about this workaround. I want to know why my code as is, not working.

Comment: @Omkar76 Type parameter T has incompatible upper bounds: View and String.  ```Log.d``` required ```String, String```. You can't return ```View```.